# How to determine if item exists in a list?

Tags: arrays, list, lua, lua-table

I made a little game and I want to check if a player name already exists in a "banlist". How can I do this if it's multiple names?
For example I have a playerlist like this:

```
 PlayerList = {'Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3'}
```

And I want to be able to ban a few players and add them to a ban list to forbid them from doing some stuff in the game. How can I do that? I can do it with 1 playername like this:

```
if (Player_Name ~= 'Player 2') then
print('Hello!!')
else
print('You are banned!')
end
```

But this would only work for "Player 2". How can I add multiple names?
I do not want to use "or", like this:

```
if (Player_Name ~= 'Player 2' or Player_Name ~= 'Player 3') then
print('Hello!!')
else
print('You are banned!')
end
```

Since my list might contain more than 200, I don't want to add over 200 "or". How can I simply check if the player is in a banlist I created? For example:

```
BanList = {'Player 2', 'Player 3'}
```

Maybe something like this (ofc this doesnt work)

```
if (Player_Name ~= BanList) then
print('Hello!!')
else
print('You are banned!')
end
```

Comment: The task has already been determined, simply use the keywords - search for "lua list contains".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a loop to iterate through all the items in your BanList and see if any of them contain the player.

```
BanList = { 'Player 2', 'Player 3' }

function isBanned(playerName)
    for _,name in pairs(BanList) do
        if name == playerName then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

if isBanned(Player_Name) then
    print('You are banned!')
else
    print('Hello!!')
end
```

Comment: One more question, how could I for example add a player to the BanList? if I would for example type /ban <name> in the game it would instantly add it to the list. Right now I need to restart the game everytime I add someone to update the list. Like /ban Player 5

Comment: `table.insert(BanList, playerName)`

Comment: This is weird. I run my .lua file in the game and when I add a player to the BanList it works in the game, but if I close the game and start it again, the player was not added to the .lua file. I add them to the list, but when I open my .lua file with notepad or whatever, I don't see their name added there. How can I make it save them permanently in the file?

Comment: Lua does not modify itself. You would need to read about file output (lookup io.open() in the Lua docs) and write a configuration file that would persist names from session to session.

You would make it save the list as the last thing it does before exit, and load the list as the first thing it does at startup.

Comment: @user3036459 You're confusing the source code for creating and initializing a list, which is text in a file, with the actual list, which is a data structure created in the memory of your computer by the Lua interpreter.  It's like a blueprint vs a house: if you put a couch in your living room, this doesn't magically add a couch to the blueprint. If you put a candle on a birthday cake, this doesn't magically add "candle" to the cake's recipe.